# How to Start an application and obtain a handle to it with Delphi?

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi

I want to start an application from Delphi, and obtain a handle to it, so I can embed the main window of said application on a frame of type TFrame. So far I have tried:

```
Function TFrmEmbeddedExe.StartNewApplication : Boolean;
var
  SEInfo: TShellExecuteInfo;
  ExitCode : DWORD;
begin

  FillChar(SEInfo, SizeOf(SEInfo), 0) ;
  SEInfo.cbSize := SizeOf(TShellExecuteInfo) ;
  with SEInfo do
  begin
    fMask := SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;
    Wnd := self.Handle;
    lpFile := PChar(self.fexecuteFileName) ;//  Example could be 'C:\Windows\Notepad.exe'
    nShow := SW_SHOWNORMAL;//SW_HIDE;
  end;

  if ShellExecuteEx(@SEInfo) then
  begin
    sleep(1500);
    self.fAppWnd := FindWindow(nil, PChar(self.fWindowCaption)); //Example : 'Untitled - Notepad'
    if self.fAppWnd <> 0 then
    begin
      Windows.SetParent(self.fAppWnd, SEInfo.Wnd);
      ShowWindow(self.fAppWnd, SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED);
      result := true;
    end
    else
      result := false;

  end

  else
    result := false;
end ;
```

The above code actually works, but `findWindow` will find any given instans of the application I started. I want to embed the exact instans that I Shellexecuted.
So if Notepad had been started a couple of times, there is no way I can get the correct one using FindWindow.

I have tried:

```
Function TfrmEmbeddedExe.CreateProcessNewApplication : Boolean;
var
zAppName: array[0..512] of char;
StartupInfo: TStartupInfo;
ProcessInfo: TProcessInformation;
Res : DWORD;
DoWait : Boolean;
begin
  DoWait := False;
  StrPCopy(zAppName, self.fexecuteFileName);  //'C:\Windows\Notepad.exe'
  FillChar(StartupInfo, Sizeof(StartupInfo), #0);
  StartupInfo.cb := Sizeof(StartupInfo);
  StartupInfo.dwFlags := STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
  StartupInfo.wShowWindow := SW_SHOWNORMAL;

  if CreateProcess (zAppName,
  nil, { pointer to command line string }
  nil, { pointer to process security attributes }
  nil, { pointer to thread security attributes }
  false, { handle inheritance flag }
  CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE or { creation flags }
  NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS,
  nil, { pointer to new environment block }
  nil, { pointer to current directory name }
  StartupInfo, { pointer to STARTUPINFO }
  ProcessInfo) then   { pointer to PROCESS_INF }
  begin
    if DoWait then  //just set it to false... so it will never enter here
    begin
      WaitforSingleObject(ProcessInfo.hProcess, INFINITE);
      GetExitCodeProcess(ProcessInfo.hProcess, Res);
    end
    else
    begin
      self.fAppWnd := ProcessInfo.hProcess;

      Windows.SetParent(self.fAppWnd, self.Handle);
      ShowWindow(self.fAppWnd, SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED);
      CloseHandle(ProcessInfo.hProcess);
      CloseHandle(ProcessInfo.hThread);


    end;

    result := true;
  end
  else begin
    Result := false;
  end;
end;
```

PLEASE DO NOT RUN THE ABOVE CODE! It produces weird results involving picking a seemingly random window anywhere in all running applications and embedding that (even menu-items from the Windows start menu..)

So basically what I need is how do I start an application, and grab a handle to the application's main window.

Comment: A process handle is not a window handle. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1888863/how-to-get-main-window-handle-from-process-id

Comment: Reading the title, I was about to come in and insist that this *must* be a duplicate, but after seeing that you're embedding this application into your own, that does set this apart. Great question.

Comment: Please don't add signatures to your post. [StackOverflow already shows one for you](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's the rough outline of what you need to do. I'll leave the coding up to you:

1. Start your process with either `ShellExecuteEx` or `CreateProcess`. This will yield a process handle.
2. Call `WaitForInputIdle` on the process handle. This gives the process a chance to load and start its message loop.
3. Pass the process handle to `GetProcessId` to obtain the process ID.
4. Use `EnumWindows` to enumerate the top level windows.
5. Pass each of these windows to `GetWindowThreadProcessId` to check whether or not you have found the top level window of your target process.
6. Once you find a window whose process ID matches your target process, you're done!

Don't forget to close your process handles once you are done with them.

Comment: David Heffernan, that does indeed sound like the way to go forward, and I'll do just that when I get the time.
Thanks a lot for explaining.

Answer (score 2):

This code works for me:

Create a "Utils"- Unit with the following >>

```
....

interface

.....

function RunProg(PName, CmdLine: String; out ProcessHdl: HWND): HWND;


implementation


type
  TEnumData = record      // Record Type for Enumeration
    WHdl: HWND;
    WPid: DWORD;
    WTitle: String;
  end;
  PEnumData = ^TEnumData;  // Pointer to Record Type

// Enumeration Function for GetWinHandleFromProcId (below)
function EnumWindowsProcMatchPID(WHdl: HWND; EData: PEnumData): bool; stdcall;
var
  Wpid : DWORD;
begin
  Result := True; // continue enumeration
  GetWindowThreadProcessID(WHdl, @Wpid);
  // Filter for only visible windows, because the Pid is not unique to the Main Form
  if (EData.WPid = Wpid) AND IsWindowVisible(WHdl) then
  begin
    EData.WHdl := WHdl;
    Result := False; // stop enumeration
  end;
end;

// Find Window from Process Id and return the Window Handle
function GetWinHandleFromProcId(ProcId: DWORD): HWND;
var
  EnumData: TEnumData;
begin
  ZeroMemory(@EnumData, SizeOf(EnumData));
  EnumData.WPid := ProcId;
  EnumWindows(@EnumWindowsProcMatchPID, LPARAM(@EnumData));
  Result := EnumData.WHdl;
end;

    
// Run Program using CreateProcess >> Return Window Handle and Process Handle
function RunProg(PName, CmdLine: String; out ProcessHdl: HWND): HWND;
var
  StartInfo: TStartupInfo;
  ProcInfo: TProcessInformation;
  ProcessId : DWORD;
  WinHdl : HWND;
  bOK : boolean;
  ix : integer;
begin
  FillChar(StartInfo, SizeOf(StartInfo), 0);
  StartInfo.cb := SizeOf(StartInfo);
  StartInfo.dwFlags := STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
  StartInfo.wShowWindow := SW_Show;
  bOK := CreateProcess(PChar(PName), PChar(CmdLine), nil, nil, False, 0, nil, nil, StartInfo, ProcInfo);
  ProcessHdl := ProcInfo.hProcess;
  ProcessId := ProcInfo.dwProcessId;

  // Note : "WaitForInputIdle" does not always wait long enough, ... 
  //          so we combine it with a repeat - until - loop >>
  WinHdl := 0;
  if bOK then  // Process is running
  begin
    WaitForInputIdle(ProcessHdl,INFINITE);
    ix := 0;
    repeat     // Will wait (up to 10+ seconds) for a program that takes very long to show it's main window
      WinHdl := GetWinHandleFromProcId(ProcessId);
      Sleep(25);
      inc(ix);
    until (WinHdl > 0) OR (ix > 400);  // Got Handle OR Timeout
  end;

  Result := WinHdl;
  CloseHandle(ProcInfo.hThread);
end;
```

Put this in your main program that uses the "Utils"- Unit >>

```
var
  SlaveWinHdl : HWND;  // Slave Program Window Handle
  SlaveProcHdl : HWND;  // Slave Program Process Handle

// Button to run Notepad - Returning Window Handle and Process Handle
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Pname, Pcmnd: string;
begin
  Pname := 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\notepad.exe';
  Pcmnd := '';
  SlaveWinHdl := RunProg(Pname, Pcmnd, SlaveProcHdl);
end;

// Button to Close program using Window Handle
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  PostMessage(SlaveWinHdl, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);
end;

// Button to Close program using Process Handle
procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TerminateProcess(SlaveProcHdl, STILL_ACTIVE);
  CloseHandle(SlaveProcHdl);
end;
```

So there you have it, a complete solution of how to Run an external program,
and then Close it by using either the Window Handle or Process Handle.

**Extra Bonus:** Sometimes you have to find the handles for a program that is already running.
You can find it based on the Window- Title with the following code (added to your “Utils” unit) >>

```
function EnumWindowsProcMatchTitle(WHdl: HWND;  EData: PEnumData): bool; stdcall; 
var
  WinTitle: array[0..255] of char;
  Wpid : DWORD;
begin
  Result := True; // continue enumeration
  GetWindowText(WHdl, WinTitle, 256);
  if (Pos(EData.WTitle, StrPas(WinTitle)) <> 0) then // Will also match partial title
  begin
    EData.WHdl := WHdl;
    GetWindowThreadProcessID(WHdl, @Wpid);
    EData.WPid := Wpid;
    Result := False; // stop enumeration
  end;
end;

function GetHandlesFromWinTitle(WinTitle: String; out ProcHdl : HWND): HWND;  
var
  EnumData: TEnumData;
begin
  ZeroMemory(@EnumData, SizeOf(EnumData));
  EnumData.WTitle := WinTitle;
  EnumWindows(@EnumWindowsProcMatchTitle, LPARAM(@EnumData));
  ProcHdl := OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS,False,EnumData.WPid);
  Result := EnumData.WHdl;
end;
```

And call it (from your main program), like this >>

```
strWT := ‘MyList.txt – Notepad’;  // example of Notepad Title
SlaveWinHdl  :=  GetHandlesFromWinTitle(strWT, SlaveProcHdl);
```