# Check if a process is a windowed process in OSX

Tags: objective-c, c, macos, cocoa, unix

Given the PID of a process, how can I check if it's a windowed process? I am looking for a solution on OSX.

Objective-C/ C solutions are wanted.
I am on OSX Mountain Lion.

I am defining a windowed process as a process that can be seen when the "Windowed Processes" tab is selected in activity monitor. http://cl.ly/FeXR

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1888944/962089) explains a process in raw win32 where you check each running window to see if it belongs to the process you want. Perhaps that helps?

Comment: @chris Thanks but I am looking for a solution for OSX in Objective-C or C.

Comment: For whatever reason, despite the numerous times you said OSX, it never registered in my brain. Apologies. Perhaps there's a similar method for OSX.

Comment: @shellter You can't be serious? Did you take the time to *read* the other question? That question asks what defining characteristics applications with icons in Activity Monitor have in common. This question asks how to check if a process is a windowed process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[NSWorkspace runningApplications]
```

This returns all the user applications in a `NSArray` as instances of `NSRunningApplication` which has a property `processIdentifier`.

Or you can use `runningApplicationWithProcessIdentifier:` directly to get the application with a specified PID.

Here is the sample code: http://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/#samplecode/AppList/Introduction/Intro.html

Through the `activationPolicy` property of the `NSRunningApplication` you could get the Windowed state. I modified the `AppList` code to make it show only the windowed applications as shown below. This matches what the activity monitor shows.

[image]

In particular, you are looking for the `NSApplicationActivationPolicyRegular`.

Note the restrictions however. This only works for user owned processes.

All other methods are deprecated and may not work in future. Methods like `GetBSDProcessList` and Carbon's `GetProcessInformation` are not recommended anymore.

Comment: I don't see how this answers my question. You have simply provided a way to retrieve all user owned processes; the only mention of checking if a process is windowed doesn't answer the question in any way.

Comment: Have you even tried the code by yourself and read the documentation that I had pointed to? Anyway, I have updated my answer to reflect how to do that.

Comment: The edit answer was very helpful! It works perfectly. Thank You for the help!