# How to get program state (for stopped working)

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm using VS C++ 2010. I need to get program state but It seems when program says It stopped working my function isn't working. I need that for restarting program if It stops working.

My Code:

```
BOOL IsProcessRunning(DWORD pid)
{
    HANDLE process = OpenProcess(SYNCHRONIZE, FALSE, pid);
    DWORD ret = WaitForSingleObject(process, 0);
    CloseHandle(process);
    return ret == WAIT_TIMEOUT;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This code can never work. If the external process has stopped running, then `OpenProcess` will fail because the process ended and the PID is no longer valid. And you don't check the value returned by `OpenProcess`. Or the PID has been re-used and then you would have a handle to the wrong process.

To use `WaitForSingleObject` in a reliable way, you need to get a handle to the process and hang on to it. Call `OpenProcess` once, and then use that handle for all subsequent calls to `WaitForSingleObject`. Call `CloseHandle` only when you are finished dealing with that process.

However, your use of `WaitForSingleObject` is simply not going to be useful for detecting that a program is not responding. In that case the call to `OpenProcess` will succeed since the process still exists and is running. The call to `WaitForSingleObject` returns `WAIT_TIMEOUT` since the process is still running. After all, a hung process is still running.

So the entire premise of your code is wrong. A hung window (or indeed any window) can only exist in a running process! You will need to throw away the code that you have and instead simply call [`IsHungAppWindow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633526.aspx). You will need a window handle for the applications main window.

Comment: Thank you !, I checked IsHungAppWindow. I'm new in C++ so I have to ask. How can I get Hwnd from other app ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1888863/how-to-get-main-window-handle-from-process-id