# C# How to minimize another application by a given process id?

Tags: c#

I would like to minimize an application by its process id. I have searched on SO and found the following code

```
private const int SW_MAXIMIZE = 3;
private const int SW_MINIMIZE = 6;
[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "FindWindow")]
public static extern IntPtr FindWindowByCaption(IntPtr ZeroOnly, string lpWindowName);
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

public void MinimizeWindow()
{
  IntPtr hwnd = FindWindowByCaption(IntPtr.Zero, "NotePad");
  ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_MINIMIZE);
}
```

But I don't want to find window by caption because the caption for an app changes. I have a given process id that is coming from another module that request minimize the app with the given process id.

Is there such a thing like this?

```
  public static extern IntPtr FindWindowByProcess(IntPtr ZeroOnly, int lpProcessID);
```

Or if not, anyway to go around?

Comment: Here's a similar question in C++ whose answers may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1888863/how-to-get-main-window-handle-from-process-id

Comment: Have a look at this prior SO answer....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1888863/how-to-get-main-window-handle-from-process-id
It looks like it offers a solution to your issue.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just use the [Process](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process(v=vs.110).aspx) class.

```
Process.GetProcessById(YourProcessID).MainWindowHandle
```

Comment: Thanks you MethodMan, That's exactly what I need: get handle by process id. Then I can do the minimize work with the handle. Thanks again.