# Golang how to set window on top

Tags: go

I am developing an app that opens a portable browser to a specific page. The thing is that every once in a while I would like to switch the focus to the browser window, so that it will appear on top of the screen if it is minimized or if there is a window on top of it.

I've tried to do this using [robotgo](https://github.com/go-vgo/robotgo), by setting the active PID to my browser's PID and setting it as active, but that didn't work:

```
robotgo.ActivePID(26360)
handle := robotgo.GetHandle()
fmt.Println("handle: %s", handle)

mdata := robotgo.GetActive()

robotgo.SetActive(mdata)
```

Is there a way to do this?

Note: since I am opening this browser process myself using `exec.Command`, I have its PID, so I don't have to search for it.

Note 2: I am running this program on Windows.

Comment: I never used `robotgo`, but isn't `mdata` the current active window, that you are setting again as the active window?

Comment: Yeah, I would expect that `mdata := robotgo.GetActive(); robotgo.SetActive(mdata)` would do nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Question is old but I had the exact same problem and I made a small package for it.

You can find it here : https://github.com/audrenbdb/goforeground

It's cross platform linux/windows; I have yet to implement it on darwin.

A summary on how it works : you enumerate all active windows and you check if PID match, once you've found the proper window you set it foreground.

On linux, it utilizes X11 (mostly); on windows win32 api. Now the trick on window is that a PID may be related to multiple windows. So we need to check two other things :
Is window active, and Is window owned (see discussion here : [How to get main window handle from process id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1888863/how-to-get-main-window-handle-from-process-id)).

Answer (score 0):

These days, you can simply run

```golang
robotgo.ActiveName("My Application Name")
```

and it will bring your application to the foreground