# Programmatically determine application status given processid

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm using Enumprocesses( lpidProcess, cb, lpcbNeeded ) to determine running ProcessIds. How do I subset this list to contain only "Applications", those processes that display on the Task Manager Applications tab?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've determined I can separate out Console and Services (as reported by tasklist) via the following: `BOOL result = ProcessIdToSessionId(ProcessId, &SessionId);

 if ( (result)&&(SessionId == WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId()) ) {
`

Comment: this could be helpful [How to get main window handle from process id?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21767578/7582247). You could probably use that to query for the window title. I'm not sure if non-applications has windows titles.

Comment: God, I love that people can read between the lines and we don't have anyone screaming, "What OS?"

Comment: The winapi tag was helpful :-)

Comment: Services always run in session 0 only. Comparing `(SessionId == WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId())` is the wrong check to make, especially since you don't really know which session `WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId()` actually returns.

Comment: Also, see [How does Task Manager categorize processes as App, Background Process, or Windows Process?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20171219-00/?p=97606) on MSDN.

Comment: The sentence _If the process has a visible window, then Task Manager calls it an "App"_  was really more helpful than most of the other answers I've seen on the topic.

Answer (score 1):

Per [How does Task Manager categorize processes as App, Background Process, or Windows Process?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20171219-00/?p=97606) on MSDN:

> **If the process has a visible window, then Task Manager calls it an "App"**.
>
> If the process is marked as critical, then Task Manager calls it a "Windows Process".
>
> Otherwise, Task Manager calls it a "Background Process".

So, given a process ID, you can check if it has any visible windows by calling `EnumWindows()`, where the callback function calls `GetWindowThreadProcessId()` to check if each window belongs to the process, and `IsWindowVisible()` to check if each window is visible.

For example:

```
struct myFindInfo
{
    DWORD processID;
    bool found;
};

static BOOL CALLBACK findVisibleWindowProc(HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam)
{
    myFindInfo *fi = reinterpret_cast<myFindInfo*>(lParam);
    DWORD pid;
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, &pid);
    if ((pid == fi->processID) && IsWindowVisible(hwnd))
    {
        fi->found = true;
        return FALSE;
    }
    return TRUE;
}

bool isApplicationProcess(DWORD processID)
{
    findInfo fi;
    fi.processID = processID;
    fi.found = false;
    EnumWindows(&findVisibleWindowProc, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(&fi));
    return fi.found;
}
```

Comment: What I have done is similar to this, however, I get only the "explorer.exe" processid, (which I don't necessarily want), and not the Application processid's. The above has very effectively weeded out the "other" Console and Services processid's reported by tasklist.