# Hot to get a window handle having the process id?

Tags: c++, windows

How can I get handle to the main process window having the process id? I knew that there is a `FindWindow` function but I don't wanna search by the window name. I just have a process id of the window's owner.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1888863/how-to-get-main-window-handle-from-process-id

Comment: Use EnumWindows + GetWindowThreadProcessId.  Beware the ambiguity, there is no mechanism in the winapi to designate a window to be the "main process window".