# How do i get a process main window position in c#?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

How do i get a process main window position. i have searched all around the internet but i cant find a solution. Here is my code:

```
        Process[] processCollection = Process.GetProcesses();
        foreach (Process p in processCollection)
        {
           // Get window position from "p"
        }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get main window handle from process id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1888863/how-to-get-main-window-handle-from-process-id)

Comment: The first step is to find the "main" window, which the duplicate shows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my unserstanding, you want to retrieve the size and position of a window in another process. If I have misunderstood you, please feel free to tell me, thanks.

check this :

[sample](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/61e5989f-8a8c-44e8-81ab-09f2e9731bc4/get-the-window-position-from-an-external-process?forum=winforms)